# I want to upload hive box as a file to cloud for backup in Flutter

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I was thinking of converting the Hive box into JSON and the backing it in the firestore as a JSON string or in the firebase storage as a file. I don't know how to do either.

```
 void backupToCloud(String name) {
    AuthController authController = Get.find();
    var messageBox = LocalX.getBoxForBackup(name);
    var mapBox = messageBox.toMap();
    var jsonBox = boxModelToJson(mapBox);
    var backupMessages = jsonBox.toString();
    // log("backupMessages: $backupMessages");
    authController.backingUpToCloud();
  }
```

messageBox variable stores the Hive box of the given name;
mapBox is messageBox converted to map (Hive has the function for conversion)
json box was me trying to convert map to json using this

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'key': key,
      'message': message,
    };
  }
```

and others are self explanatory.

Now what to do?
I was also thinking if I can get the HiveBox file I can upload it to drive via share or firebase cloud storage; but how can I get the file?

Converting Hive box into json or finding an alternative way to upload Hive Box file into cloud

Comment: Why you want to use Hive. Firestore has its own locally data saving mechanism.

Comment: i want to save my phones chat history but i am not using firebase cloud messaging i am using ble to connect 2 phones as peer to peer. so how would you suggest i should backup my chats in cloud?